# Filtering on a GroupTable

Tags: java, swing, jide

I have a `GroupTable` where the grouping is done based on the first column. Is there a way to filter the `GroupTableModel` based on the nodes under the Grouped node and not based on the grouped node (i.e col 1).

Comment: It would be good to share any pertinent code so people can more accurately help you.

Comment: We have QuickTreeFilterField  which takes in a treeModel as an argument  wherein when we search for a key word, it displays only those nodes of the tree model that matches the entered keyword. I am searching for a similar workflow where my model should show only those nodes under the grouped node which matches the searched keyword.

Comment: *"We have.."*  Do you understand the difference between 'pertinent code' as suggested by @cryptic_star and a 'vague description of the code'?  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).